# how to un-substitute paramters in Lumen route

Tags: laravel, lumen

Say if I defined a route `GET /user/{user_id}/post/{post_id}`.  **How do I get the un-substitute route in middleware?**  i.e. if the request is `GET /usr/123/post/456`, is there a pre-defined function that can get me `/user/{user_id}/post/{post_id}`?

I am currently using following snippet

```
   $urlParam = $request->route()[2];
   if (isset($urlParam) && count($urlParam)) {
       $urlPath = substr(str_replace(
           array_map(function($item) { return "/" . $item . "/"; }, array_values($urlParam)),
           array_map(function($item) { return "/{" . $item . "}/"; }, array_keys($urlParam)),
           "/" . $request->path() . "/"), 1, -1);
   }
   return $urlPath;
```

but as you can see this is not bug-free, if both user_id & post_id are the same, above snippet will not generate right result.

Answer (score 0):

**In Laravel**

If you wan to get the same route URI you can use

```
$request->route()->uri();
```

This will return `user/{user_id}/post/{post_id}`

**In Lumen**

```
$segments = $request->segments();

foreach ($request->route()[2] as $parameter => $value) {
    $segment_index = array_search($value, $request->segments());
    $segments[$segment_index] = "{{$parameter}}";
}

$segments = implode('/', $segments);

dd($segments);
```

And the result will be `user/{user_id}/post/{post_id}`

Comment: while this works in Laravel, it does not work in Lumen.  Does anyone know how to do the same thing in Lumen?